# Почему System.String.Empty не null?

Tags: c#

Доброго.

Возможно, мой вопрос ставит в тупик своей некорректностью, но это лишь для того, чтобы вы прочувствовали то же, что и я.

Я декомпилировал mscorelib.dll v4.0 двумя декомпиляторами (dotPeek и ILSpy), и оба мне показали, что это поле `readonly` и НЕ инициализировано в классе. Класс НЕ `partial`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, при выполнении всё нормально и `string.Empty is ""`, но может мне кто-то объяснить почему так? Где тогда инициализируется поле, если не здесь (static конструктора также не найдено)? Или эти декомпиляторы что-то не видят?

Comment: [The Empty constant holds the empty string value. **It is initialized by the EE during startup.** It is treated as intrinsic by the JIT as so the static constructor would never run. Leaving it uninitialized would confuse debuggers. We need to call the String constructor so that the compiler doesn't mark this as a literal. Marking this as a literal would mean that it doesn't show up as a field which we can access from native.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,69)

Comment: Думаю эта тайна разгадывается атрибутом `__DynamicallyInvokable`, а возможно флагом interlnal. Не всё можно "Запихнуть" в библиотеку, некоторые части ПЗ подключаются "особым" образом (механизмом).

Comment: readonly  - означает, что свойство будет задано при инициализации класса, но не запрещено, что бы инициализатор их задавал "на своё усмотрение" (т.е. даже если в процедуре инициализации его нету).

Comment: @Grundy: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, надо оформить хорошо, плюс описать что за ЕЕ :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Именно так! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смотрите, в инициализации базовых частей языка иногда не обойтись без магии.

Например, как вы думаете, как можно описать на C# структуры наподобие `int`? У структуры есть скрытое поле `m_value` типа... `int`! У обыкновенных структур это не могло бы быть скомпилировано, но компилятор при компиляции этого класса знает, что это внутренний тип, и обрабатывает его особенным образом.

Такая же точно магия случается при использовании `string.Empty`. В Майкрософтовской реализации JIT-компилятор знает, что `string.Empty` — специальное значение, и заменяет его на константу. Это нужно для оптимизации: данное поле используется очень часто.

В принципе, можно было бы в таком случае и никогда не инициализировать это поле, но тогда рефлексия и отладчики будут видеть «неправильное» значение, что, конечно, нехорошо. Для этого поле всё же отдельно инициализируется средой выполнения, которая тоже знает этот специальный случай. (Почему не через статический конструктор? Можно предположить, что вызов статического конструктора — относительно дорогая вещь, т. к. он обязан совершать глобальную блокировку на случай одновременного вызова статического конструктора в нескольких потоках.)

---

Всё это, конечно, специфика текущей версии реализации компиляторов и рантайм-библиотеки Майкрософт; в других реализациях (например, Mono) в этом конкретном месте может и не быть никакой магии.

---

Лавры первооткрывателя истины принадлежат @Grundy, который «раскопал» точную причину и указал на неё в своём комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо) А я ведь даже не задумался о рекурсии в подобных случаях - камень в мой огород... 
А можете порекомендовать какую-то статью/блог/книгу по магии компиляторов (JIT и обычного)?

Comment: @AlexKubasov: Пожалуйста! На самом деле в реализации языков много подводных камней. Где почитать, я сам не знаю: находил информацию по частям в интернете случайно.